# Any free ASP.NET CMS for features such as events, photo gallery, videos, newsletters etc?

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system

Recommend a free ASP.NET CMS that offers to build a website with features such as photo gallery, videos, events, mailing lists etc

Answer (score 2):

The first two names that come to mind are [`mojoportal`](http://www.mojoportal.com/) and [`dotnetnuke`](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)

[`Top 7 ASP.NET CMS Options`](http://webmasterformat.com/blog/top-asp-net-cmss) are listed here.
For indepth insight, read [`DotnetNuke vs Kenticko vs Umbraco`](http://webmasterformat.com/blog/dotnetnuke-vs-kentico-vs-umbraco) comparison also.

Oops, I just found out that I had asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/333148/17447). May come handy.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/) it is a very good CMS, have been using it for the  past few month. even http://asp.net is made in umbraco

**Edit**

This might be interesting to: 
http://webmasterformat.com/tools/cms

Comment: WTF? How is ASP.NET made in Umbraco? Dont you mean the other way around?

Comment: The webpage "asp.net" is made in umbraco xD

Comment: > seems like umbraco is unaware of it. please add to list here http://umbraco.org/get-started/case-studies/sites-running-umbraco

Comment: Hmm maybe im worng then, just what i heard :S

Comment: > no offense. i was so taken back that i did a google search asap. :)

Answer (score 0):

If, as your question suggests, you're looking to quickly build a site with off-the-shelf components, http://www.dotnetnuke.com/ would probably be your best option due to the sheer number of extensions that are available (see http://forge.dotnetnuke.com/ and http://www.snowcovered.com/, or your favourite search engine).

If you're planning to do a fair bit of custom development, then you may find http://umbraco.org/ more to your taste.